# what does the ては mean here?

Tags: grammar

道すがら、近所に住む人達に会っ**ては**挨拶をしたのですが、無愛想な彼女は短い尻尾をゆらゆらさせるだけで、つーんと顔をそらしていました。

I have figured out it may be simillar to たら etc., but im not so sure.